# In Ruby, How do I configure the suffix used while rotating logs using Logger?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, logging

I using Logger to rotate files on a daily basis. I noticed that Logger rotates files using a date suffix in the following format:

```
${logname}.YYYYMMDD
```

However, I want it to suffix in the following format:

```
${logname}.YYYY-MM-DD
```

Any ideas how I can achieve this?

Comment: The reason an extension would be in `YYYYMMDD` format is it makes it very easy to roll files based on the date. It is almost simple math, after taking into account the days in the months and converting the value into an integer. Using `YYYY-MM-DD` isn't much harder, but you'll have to recreate the integer value, or parse it as a date then rebuild the format. Personally, I think that would be a nice extension to Logger, so maybe you should get it working and submit it as a patch.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From looking at the [source](https://github.com/nahi/logger/blob/master/lib/logger.rb#L635), it seems the date format is hardcoded:

```
def shift_log_period(period_end)
      postfix = period_end.strftime("%Y%m%d") # YYYYMMDD
```

So, short of renaming the created file(s) via a scheduled job I guess there is no way of doing this.

Comment: but you always can monkey-patch Logger class ;)

Comment: To make things worse, the method is private so we cannot override it either. I landed up using a different logging library

Answer (score 0):

You can set the logging configuration in application.rb like

`config.logger = Logger.new("path/to/logs/",NO_OF_LOG_FILES, SIZE_OF_EACH_LOG)` for more info check [this](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/logger/rdoc/Logger.html) out

Comment: This doesn't really answer the question